# MKR 1010 disconnects COM-port on each upload

Tags: communication, windows, mkr1010

Each time I attempt to upload to the *MKR WiFi 1010* board the COM-port gets disconnected, usually at one of the following points:

1. Either it disconnects just after compiling/verifying. In this case the `LED_BUILTIN` pulsates slowly, and the USB-cable needs to be reconnected in order to try again. The next attempt usually results in `2.`.
2. Or, it disconnects after a successful upload. The next attempt to upload will always result in `1.` occurring. When this happens the COM-port is still visible in Windows Device Manager but it can't be found by a Serial Monitor.

Any ideas what could be causing this or what could be done to have it stay connected? With an *UNO* this doesn't happen.

Comment: does it happen only with your sketch or with Blink too? Uno has external Serial chip. on MKR the MCU handles the USB so as it resets the port disconnects

Answer (score 1):

This was due to using a virtual machine (VMware) which apparently doesn't handle the MKR board COM-port so well. Moving the development environment to the host solved the problem. It still disconnects the COM-port after upload but then consistently reconnects to the same COM-port and that's good enough.